# Python: Define every item in List as set

Tags: python, set

#### What I have:

I have this List:

```
[in]:  a=['Hamburg','Berlin','Teheran','Chicago']
[out]: ['Hamburg', 'Berlin', 'Teheran', 'Chigaco']
```

#### What i did:

I convert this list to set

```
[in]: set_a=set(a)
[out]: {'Chigaco', 'Berlin', 'Hamburg', 'Teheran'}
```

#### What I want:

```
[{'Chigaco'}, {'Berlin'}, {'Hamburg'}, {'Teheran'}]
```

Comment: That's invalid and thus impossible.

Comment: You can't have a set of sets. Sets are unhashable.

Comment: Its possible but Brackets needed in b :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brackets needed in b :

```
a=['Hamburg','Berlin','Teheran','Chicago']
b=[set([el]) for el in a]
```

Comment: Works 100%..Thanks

Comment: I understand the other comments: beware, this is not a set of sets. ;)